# Parse html tables from emails to lists then convert to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I’m  an absolute Beginner in Python , and I am trying to create a script which loops through an email folder and grabs a html table within the emails and convert to a pandas dataframe for export to excel.

The code below loops through the folder and adds each table and its contents to a list []

```
# importing the libraries
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# connect to outlook email inbox
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi= outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = mapi.Folders['emailaddress'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Testfolder']
Mail_Messages = inbox.Items


# loop through email folder and seach for table in email messages and add to a list

output = []
for mail in Mail_Messages:
    body = mail.HTMLBody
    html_body = BeautifulSoup(body,"lxml")
    html_tables = html_body.find('table')
    
    # read html table to dataframe list

    df = pd.read_html(str(html_tables))
    #pd.concat(df).set_index(0).T
    df= df[0].set_index(0).T
    df.reset_index(level=None, drop=True, inplace=False, col_level=0, col_fill='')
    output.append(df)

    #print (df)
    
print(output)

[0 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
1  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8, 0 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
1  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8, 0 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
1  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8]
```

What I’m trying to achieve is, for every table in the email folder add the table to a new row
So it would finally end up something like this

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8
```

I’m struggling to get the lists that are created into a structure that could be converted into a pandas dataframe to be exported to excel.

As I’ve said I’m a beginner , and looking some help on how this could be achieved.

Here's a screenshot of the table i'm tring to grab..
[image: Picture of the table in the email below.]

Comment: `df[0].set_index(0).T` pd.read_html returns a list of dataframes, you havea list with one dataframe. df[0] gets the first element of this list.  Next, use set index to move column 0, into the index you may need set_index('0') depending on if that column headers is a string or integer. Last, transpose the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Scott !!! that helps,  how could this work in a loop when there could be multiple tables to bring together in one dataframe?

Comment: @Dante `pd.concat(df).set_index(0).T` to combine all tables in `df` before transposing

Comment: @Driftr95 , i'm still struggling to get the lists into a dataframe to export to excel.
i currently get this as the output for the 3 emails that contain the tables.
[0 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
1  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8, 0 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
1  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8, 0 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
1  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a list of dataframes (`df`) that looked like

```py
[         0        1
 0  Column1  Value1a
 1  Column2  Value2a
 2  Column3  Value3a
 3  Column4  Value4a
 4  Column5  Value5a
 5  Column6  Value6a
 6  Column7  Value7a
 7  Column8  Value8a,
          0        1
 0  Column1  Value1b
 1  Column2  Value2b
 2  Column3  Value3b
 3  Column4  Value4b
 4  Column5  Value5b
 5  Column6  Value6b
 6  Column7  Value7b
 7  Column8  Value8b,
          0        1
 0  Column1  Value1c
 1  Column2  Value2c
 2  Column3  Value3c
 3  Column4  Value4c
 4  Column5  Value5c
 5  Column6  Value6c
 6  Column7  Value7c
 7  Column8  Value8c]
```

then **`pd.concat([d.set_index(d.columns[0]) for d in df], axis='columns', ignore_index=True).T`** would return a single Dataframe

| index | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Column8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Value1a | Value2a | Value3a | Value4a | Value5a | Value6a | Value7a | Value8a |
| 1 | Value1b | Value2b | Value3b | Value4b | Value5b | Value6b | Value7b | Value8b |
| 2 | Value1c | Value2c | Value3c | Value4c | Value5c | Value6c | Value7c | Value8c |

---

But if `df` was instead oriented as

```py
[         0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7
 0  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8
 1  Value1a  Value2a  Value3a  Value4a  Value5a  Value6a  Value7a  Value8a,
          0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7
 0  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8
 1  Value1b  Value2b  Value3b  Value4b  Value5b  Value6b  Value7b  Value8b,
          0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7
 0  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8
 1  Value1c  Value2c  Value3c  Value4c  Value5c  Value6c  Value7c  Value8c]
```

then

```py
pd.concat([d.rename(columns=d.iloc[0]).drop(d.index[0]) for d in df], ignore_index=True)
```

would return the same combined DataFrame.

---

If you leave out `ignore_index=True` then the rows will have the same indexes from before combining; i.e., 1,1,1 instead of 0,1,2.

---

---

**ADDED EDIT:**

If you just want the tables from each message in one combined Dataframe, this should do:

```py
pd.concat([mdf.set_index(mdf.columns[0]) for mdf in [
    (pd.read_html(str(mtable))[0] if mtable else None) for mtable in 
    [BeautifulSoup(m.HTMLBody, "lxml").find('table') for m in Mail_Messages] 
] if mdf is not None], axis='columns', ignore_index=True).T
```

| [image: SampleOp] |
| --- |

---

but if you want/need the loop for anything else, then you can also do

```py
output = []
for mail in Mail_Messages:
    html_tables = BeautifulSoup(mail.HTMLBody, "lxml").find('table')
    
    # read html table to dataframe list
    df = pd.read_html(str(html_tables))[0]
    output.append(df.set_index(df.columns[0]))

    ## WHATEVER ELSE YOU NEED TO DO IN THE LOOP ##

output = pd.concat(output, axis='columns', ignore_index=True).T
print(output)
```

and that should print something like

```
0 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
0  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8
1  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8
2  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6  Value7  Value8
```

Comment: if i add 
pd.concat([d.set_index(0) for d in df], axis='columns', ignore_index=True).T

i recieve this error

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: where would I add your suggestion to the current code?
I do apologize , i'm a total newbie

Comment: @Dante you should add it at whichever point in your code `df` is in the format described in the answer (I assumed it was right after `df = pd.read_html(str(html_tables))` but I can't be sure without seeing a sample of `html_tables`). And as for the error, are you using `d` as a variable name for something already? Or maybe I'm mistaken about your original df's column names [it's safer to use `d.set_index(d.columns[0])` anyway - I've edited my answer].

Comment: @Dante If the edited version doesn't work when added right after `read_html` line and you do already have a variable `d` try changing `d` [all instances in *my* code only] to some other name you're not using yet (I think that's unlikely to be the reason, but it's worth a try....). If it still doesn't work I would need a sample of `html_tables` to check what's causing the issue

Comment: Thanks for all your help .. I've added a screen shot of the table im trying to grab from each email..  obviously i've changed the data in the table ,  but thats the table structure..

Comment: @Dante I need the **HTML** of the table actually (could you print `html_tables`?), but arranged the way it is, `pd.concat([d.set_index(d.columns[0]) for d in pd.read_html(str(html_tables))], axis='columns', ignore_index=True).T` *should* work...it's still not working?

Comment: i've posted the html from the email the table ,  again i appreciate your time in helping me..

Comment: @Dante it *should* work - I pasted your html and ran that line and got [**this** output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v14n8.png) . So, the only reason I can think of for `AttributeError` is - are you *sure* you don't already have a variable called `d`? (although even then, it shouldn't be an issue.... still, try changing to something like **`pd.concat([tdf.set_index(tdf.columns[0]) for tdf in pd.read_html(str(body))], axis='columns', ignore_index=True).T`** and see if you still get the error)

Comment: ok i got rid of the error, but i still cannot get the lists into the dataframe as you have demonstrated.   i've added what the output i receive with and without your line of code.

Comment: @Dante I didn't realize you were tying to combine tables from different emails/htmls - in which case, you would need to `concat` **outside** the loop. Please see my added edit

Comment: yes this is exactly what i was trying to achieve ...  Thank you so much , i really appreciate the time you've taken to help me...   One last question ,  how could i now get the dataframe into a excel / csv file from with your code example ?

Comment: @Dante you can use [`.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) [ or [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) +  [`.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel) ]